# BB Dialog showing up before alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

[JSFiddle Link:](https://jsfiddle.net/kox5tw0k/)

The `bootbox.alert` should show up before the `bootbox.dialog`. I've preloaded all the libraries into the JSFiddle. I want the `bootbox.dialog` to show up once the `bootbox.alert` has been clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kox5tw0k/1/)

Bootbox defined their functions [here](http://bootboxjs.com/), and as you can see they include a callback. For example:

```
bootbox.alert(message, callback)
```

The `callback` gives you the option to only run certain code once this line is completed. This solves your problem.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.begin-game').click(function () {
        bootbox.alert("This should show up first", function () {
            bootbox.dialog({
                message: "Did you pass Go?",
                title: "This should go second / last",
                buttons: {
                    // Passed go
                    success: {
                        label: "Yes I Passed GO!",
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function () {

                        }
                    },
                    // Did not pass go
                    danger: {
                        label: "I did not :(",
                        className: "btn-danger",
                        callback: function () {

                        }
                    },
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter to `bootbox.alert` is a `function` that will be called after the alert is dismissed. Launch the dialog in that function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.begin-game').click(function () {
        bootbox.alert("This should show up first", showDialog);

        function showDialog() {
            bootbox.dialog({
                message: "Did you pass Go?",
                title: "This should go second / last",
                buttons: {
                    // Passed go
                    success: {
                        label: "Yes I Passed GO!",
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function() {

                        }
                    },
                    // Did not pass go
                    danger: {
                        label: "I did not :(",
                        className: "btn-danger",
                        callback: function() {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });        
        }
    });
});
```